# In Excel, how can I get the maximum number with a condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I use the Col A as the id number for my data, and the ID number begins at the year. Such as 2018xxxxxxx. I want to get the *maximum* id number for a year.

In Python, use a simple condition check, and then I can get the result. Such as.

```
col_A_max = max([x for x in range(A) if str(x) == '2016'])
```

I tried to rewrite it in Excel, but it did not work.

```
=max(if(A:A, left(A:A, 4) = "2016", A:A))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this array formula:

```
=max(if(left(A:A, 4) = "2016", A:A))
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm. (The first six characters will never be "2018".)

This might depend on whether you are using dates.

Comment: I did not use the "Ctrl, Shift and Enter" that is the problem. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

## MAX Array Formula

The following are array formulas. After they are entered (copied) to the formula bar, hold `LEFT CONTROL + SHIFT` and press `ENTER`. (Enter them without the curly braces ({})).

> ```
> {=MAX((LEFT(A:A,4)="2016")*A:A)}
> ```

```
{=MAX((LEFT(A$1:A$20,4)="2016")*A$1:A$20)}
```

The following image demonstrates how this formula will work if the values in the `A` column are either numbers or numbers formatted as text, while the other formulas will not. This principle cannot be applied to `MIN`.

[image]